# Solving shift/reduce conflict in expression grammar

Tags: parsing, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

I am new to bison and I am trying to make a grammar parsing expressions.
I am facing a shift/reduce conflight right now I am not able to solve.

The grammar is the following:

```
%left "[" "("
%left "+"

%%

expression_list : expression_list "," expression
                | expression 
                | /*empty*/
                ;


expression :  "(" expression ")"  
           |  STRING_LITERAL      
           |  INTEGER_LITERAL           
           |  DOUBLE_LITERAL
           |  expression "(" expression_list ")" /*function call*/
           |  expression "[" expression "]" /*index access*/
           |  expression "+" expression         
           ;
```

This is my grammar, but I am facing a shift/reduce conflict with those two rules `"(" expression ")"` and `expression "(" expression_list ")"`.
How can I resolve this conflict?

EDIT: I know I could solve this using precedence climbing, but I would like to not do so, because this is only a small part of the expression grammar, and the size of the expression grammar would explode using precedence climbing.

Comment: If that is the entirety of your grammar, it has no shift-reduce conflict. However, I doubt it is your entire grammar.

Comment: wow I feel realy stupid right now... I found a typo in another rule, which affected this one

Comment: That's why we ask for a [mcve], which is very different from "a few lines of my code". If you produce the [mcve], it will often solve your problem for you by helping you clarify the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shift-reduce conflict in the grammar as presented, so I suppose that it is just an excerpt of the full grammar. In particular, there will be precisely the shift/reduce conflict mentioned if the real grammar includes:

```
%start program
%%
program: %empty
       | program expression
```

In that case, you will run into an ambiguity because given, for example, `a(b)`, the parser cannot tell whether it is a single call-expression or two consecutive expressions, first a single variable, and second a parenthesized expression. To avoid this problem you need to have some token which separates expression (statements).

There are some other issues:

```
expression_list : expression_list "," expression
                | expression 
                | /*empty*/
                ;
```

That allows an expression list to be `,foo` (as in `f(,foo)`), which is likely not desirable. Better would be

```
arguments: %empty
         | expr_list
expr_list: expr
         | expr_list ',' expr
```

And the precedences are probably backwards. Usually one wants postfix operators like call and index to bind more tightly than arithmetic operators, so they should come at the end. Otherwise `a+b(7)` is `(a+b)(7)`, which is unconventional.